# How to get $data['string'] from another function to index function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to set api and endpoint REST API from another function. How to I get api and endpoint value from another function to index function?

I tried use `$url= file_get_content($data['api'].$data['endpoint'])` but didn't work for me.

```
public function getData() {
        $data['api'] = $this->input->post('api');
        $data['endpoint'] = $this->input->post('endpoint');
        return $data;
    }
```

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');
        $data['api'] = $this->input->post('api');
        $data['endpoint'] = $this->input->post('endpoint');
        $files= $data['api'].$data['endpoint'];
        $url_json = file_get_contents($files);
    }
```

Message: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Comment: `getData()` in same class?

Comment: yes, getData() and index() in same class